# Objects are not valid as a React child. Trying to render HTML elements in react that are created by a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, render

I am trying to build a UI for a website builder where the user can can create components and add them to a website. Once the options are selected, I am having trouble creating the element with my js function to render it onto my react page.

Please See My code below

```
const Page = () => {

  componentList = [{
    details: {
      content: 'Example Title',
      fontSize: 'large',
      fontType: 'Rubik',
      color: '#e67e22'
    },
    type: 'heading'
  }]

  const createHtmlElements = (component: Component) => {
    if (component.type === "heading") {
      let heading = document.createElement("h2");
      heading.innerHTML = component.details.content;
      return heading;
    }
  };


  

  const renderComponents = componentList.map((component) => {
    return createHtmlElements(component);
  });

  console.log(renderComponents);

  return (
    <>
      {renderComponents}

    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

What exactly would I need to do here to render onto my react page an HTML heading with the content displayed inside of it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

P.S Next step will be styling the built component using the attributes so any tips on that wwould be greatly appreciated as well

Thanks,

Comment: Fix your data array to sensible format. If that is what you're receiving, modify it in your component/state all at once.

Answer (score -1):

Replace return statement with the below code :

```
 return <renderComponents />;
```

Reason: Here renderComponent is React component, not a variable as per React rules, Hence you cannot treat it as a variable.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**:
1.First import React in your code.

```
import React from 'react';
```

2.Change type in component List:

```
type: 'h2',
```

3.Change the `createHTMLElements` function to this .Here you should   React elements instead of DOM elements.

```
 const createHtmlElements = (component) => {
    const { details: { content, style }, type } = component;

    return React.createElement(
      type,
      { style },
      content
    );
  };
```

Rest of the code will remain same . The **final code** wil look like this:

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const componentList = [
    {
      details: {
        content: "Example Title",
        fontSize: "large",
        fontType: "Rubik",
        color: "#e67e22"
      },
      type: "h2"
    }
  ];

  const createHtmlElements = (component) => {
    const { details: { content, fontSize, fontType, color }, type } = component;
    
    const style = {
      fontSize,
      fontFamily: fontType,
      color
    };

    return React.createElement(
      type,
      { style },
      content
    );
  };

  const RenderComponents = componentList.map((component, index) => {
    return createHtmlElements(component);
  });

  return (
    <>
      {RenderComponents}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Better not to mix content and style together. Just closely look how the **componentList[]** should look like. Also the type should directly annotate the actual html element. If you still returns it as 'header', then control if from the code(in createHtmlElements).

```
function App() {
  let componentList = [{
    details: {
      content: 'Example Title',
      style: {
        fontSize: 'large',
        fontType: 'Rubik',
        color: '#e67e22',
      }
    },
    type: 'h2',
  }]

  const createHtmlElements = (component) => {
    const { details: { content, style }, type } = component;

    return React.createElement(
      type,
      { style },
      content
    );
  };


  const renderComponents = componentList.map((component) => {
    return createHtmlElements(component);
  });


  return (
    <>
      {renderComponents}
    </>
  );
}
```

ps: Refer to ***createElement*** api to understand how you can easily create React elements.